# Django - SELECT row with largest SUM of related child, GROUP BY related parent

Tags: python, django, postgresql, distinct, annotate

I have three models defined like this:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()

class Market(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Issue(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market,related_name='issues',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    volume = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

It is structured like this:

Every `Match` has several `Market`, and every `Market` has several `Issue`.

What I want to do is:
**For each Match, select the Market that has the largest sum of Issue.volume**

It may sound quite easy, but I can't figure it out...

What I've done so far:

1. **Without the `DISTINCT Match` condition**

```
Market.objects.annotate(total_volume=Sum('issues__volume')).order_by("-total_volume")
```

This works as expected, but a single `Match` occurs multiple time in my QuerySet.

2. **First try with the `DISTINCT Match` condition**

Then I'm trying to add a `DISTINCT(Match)`. As I'm using Postgresql, I can use `distinct('match_id')`:

```
Market.objects.annotate(total_volume=Sum('issues__volume')).order_by("match","-total_volume").distinct("match_id")
```

But it raises the following error:
`NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.`

3. **Second try with the `DISTINCT Match` condition**

I achieved to get what I expected using:

```
Market.objects.values('match_id').annotate(total_volume=Sum('issues__volume')).order_by("-total_volume")
```

However, I want to access to every `Issue` linked to a specific `Market`, which is impossible here because of the use of `values()`.

Do you have any ideas on how to make it work with as few requests as possible?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

It appears to be working by resorting to Subquery:

```
l = Market.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('pk')).annotate(vol=Sum('issues__volume'))

Market.objects.annotate(total_volume=Subquery(l.values('vol')[:1])).order_by("match_id","-total_volume").distinct("match")
```

It can prevent the error `NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) not implemented`, but I can't know why exactly!